# ClassCast Exception is thrown after I've used ASM Toolkit to replace the body of a static method

Tags: java, bytecode

I've been trying to use the ASM bytecode toolkit to replace the body of a public and static method in a class. The actual body replacement seems to work fine and I do get the expected behavior if execute the following once the transformation has completed:

```
Class cls = loadClass("ext.hm.cmd.MyProg");
cls.getMethod("hello").invoke(instance);
```

However if I try to cast the new instance to MyProg like so

```
MyProg p =  (MyProg) instance;
p.hello();
```

I get the error message:
java.lang.ClassCastException: ext.hm.cmd.MyProg cannot be cast to ext.hm.cmd.MyProg

As I'm not adding or deleting any methods in the class I can't really understand why I get this error. Has anyone seen this before and if so, what is the cause of it and how can I solve it?

Thanks
Daniel Martinsson

Answer (score 3):

Kind of a guess, but I'd say you have the same named class loaded by two different ClassLoaders.  Those are actually considered two separate classes and one cannot be cast to the other.

One is loaded before the line

```
 MyProg p =  (MyProg) instance;
```

is executed.  The other is loaded through your call to `loadClass`.

To fix this you would probably need the class that performs the line of code above to be *loaded* by the **same** ClassLoader that loads the altered instance of MyProg.  Then it should work.

Comment: +1 on the different Class instances. However, to fix it, better transform an original class, i.e. transform it before the class is loaded at the first time.

Comment: I'm not sure that I can transform the class when it is first loaded as I only need (and have access to) the class in one spot while it may still be used in its original state in other parts of the application.  How far up would this loader hierarchy have to go? Can I use classA, which is loaded normally, to load MyProgProvider using the custom ClassLoader which then in turn uses the same custom ClassLoader instance to load MyProg?

Comment: @Daniel:  The easiest way is to have an interface or super type MyProgSuper that both versions of the class extend/implement, and only deal with that interface or super type.

Answer (score 0):

If you use spring boot dev tool, you can try exclude it from the project